# Lua Script function for Wireshark to find answer message

Tags: lua, wireshark

I'm writing a Lua acript for Wireshark to dissect a private protocol. I'm currently looking for a function which can provide the message number of the answer to the current message.

My protocol is sending requests with a `Sequence Number` and the answer is containing the same `Sequence Number`.

Typically I would like to have a function which could return the `Message Number` of the answer and would return a `null` value if there is no answer. Something like:

```
AnswerMessageNumber = Get.MessageNumberWhere(MyProto.AnswerSequenceNumber = MyProto.RequestSequenceNumber)
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

As of this writing, it's not yet possible to track conversations with Lua, but there is an open Wireshark Issue requesting this feature, namely [Add Lua support for tracking conversations](https://gitlab.com/wireshark/wireshark/-/issues/15396).  Once implemented, you will be able to track requests/responses with some modifications to your Lua script of course.  This issue has been open for at least 3 years though, so unfortunately it seems unlikely to be implemented any time soon.